# Two UITableViewCells in One Row

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can somebody expain how to put two uitableview cells in one row, as per whatsapp screenshot below with +353 and Phone Number? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They might be just two `UITextField`s in a single table cell.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

1. You can design whole as in a UIView and add to the cell.
2. Create only create the view for phone number input and add into the footer of table and leave other as cell.